# Cannot display values of dictionary on my Flask webpage in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, flask, jinja2

I am trying to display the values contained in a dictionary on my flask webpage. I am able to display it on the terminal,but i am Unable to display it on the webpage. So there is a section of my webpage which has a graph and I am trying to display the values on that graph. The X axis of the graph has certain dates while Y-Axis hosts a certain no of values.
Here is my function in which displays the dictionary on my terminal but upon retrieving the values from my postgresQl Tables it throws up an error.
myfunc

```
    def stats(self, application):
       
        '''
        In this section

        GET
        Graph : for the last 30 days the number of request (stack bars) and as line
        Tables: for each campaign the matrix with the winning for segment

        POST
        Add a new arm to  the DLP (to every single bandit)2
        '''

        if request.method == 'POST':
            new_url = request.form['site_url']

            self.add_arm(new_url)

        # table for each campaign
        self.tables = {}
        landing_req = Landing_request.query.all()
        for rows in landing_req:
            self.tables[rows.campaign_id] = rows.campaign_id

        # Graph structure
        self.graph = {}
        lr = Landing_request.query.all()
        for rows in lr:
            self.graph[rows.id] = rows.id
        application.logger.info(f'Campaign inside the system - {len(self.bandit_campaigns)}')

        # for every campaign
        for campaign in self.bandit_campaigns:

            # Return the structure of the features
            x_list = self.Feature_inst.x_feature_dict.items()

            # Then I return the Improvement and the status of the single features
            best_value, status_ele = self.bandit[campaign].return_status(x_list)

            # application.logger.info(f'status_ele - {status_ele}')

            status_ele_pure = {a: self._ranked_status(k) for a, k in status_ele.items()}

            # for every device
            for device in status_ele_pure.keys():

                # for every page
                for page in status_ele_pure[device].keys():

                    if campaign in self.pages.keys():

                        if page in self.pages[campaign][device].keys():

                            status_ele_pure[device][page]['impressions'] = self.pages[campaign][device][page][
                                'impressions']
                            status_ele_pure[device][page]['conversions'] = self.pages[campaign][device][page][
                                'conversions']
                            status_ele_pure[device][page]['rate'] = self.pages[campaign][device][page]['rate']
                        else:
                            status_ele_pure[device][page]['impressions'] = 0
                            status_ele_pure[device][page]['conversions'] = 0
                            status_ele_pure[device][page]['rate'] = 0

                    else:

                        status_ele_pure[device][page]['impressions'] = 0
                        status_ele_pure[device][page]['conversions'] = 0
                        status_ele_pure[device][page]['rate'] = 0

                        # I will save the best and the matrix

            self.tables[campaign] = status_ele_pure

        today = datetime.datetime.now()

        # for all the campaign
        for campaign_id in self.bandit_campaigns:

            if campaign_id not in self.graph.keys():
                # Graph
                self.graph[campaign_id] = {}

            # I print the last 30 days data
            for i_day in range(30):

                # Select the day id
                eventid_i = (today - timedelta(days=i_day)).strftime('%Y%m%d')

                # If it's not there I initialize the system
                if eventid_i not in self.graph[campaign_id].keys():
                    self.graph[campaign_id][eventid_i] = {}

                # If there is the data
                if eventid_i in self.selection[campaign_id].keys():

                    self.graph[campaign_id][eventid_i] = self.selection[campaign_id][eventid_i]

                else:
                    self.graph[campaign_id][eventid_i] = None

        application.logger.info(f'selection - {self.selection}')

        application.logger.info(f'graph - {self.graph}')

        application.logger.info(f'tables - {self.tables}')
```

and here is the html part

```
<tbody>
                            {% for key,value in tables.items()  %}
                            <tr>
                            <td class="element">{{key}}</td>
                             <td class="element">

                                    {% for key_page,value in value[0].items()  %}
                                 <div class="box"> 
    
             
                                    <div>Page {{structure[key_page]}}</div>
                                    <div>Rank: {{value['rank']}} </div>
                    <div>Impressions: {{value['impressions']}} </div>
                    <div>Conversions: {{value['conversions']}} </div>
                    <div>Conversion rate: {{'%0.2f' % value['rate']|float}}%</div>

                                </div>
                                    {% endfor %}

                    
                             </td>
                             <td class="element">
                                        {% for key_page,value in value[1].items()  %}
                                 <div class="box"> 

       
                                    <div>Page {{structure[key_page]}}</div> 
                                    <div>Rank: {{value['rank']}} </div>
                    <div>Impressions: {{value['impressions']}} </div>
                    <div>Conversions: {{value['conversions']}} </div>
                    <div>Conversion rate: {{'%0.2f' % value['rate']|float}}%</div>

                                </div>
                                    {% endfor %}


                             </td>
###rest of code
```

and this throws an error like: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: str object has no element 0
I have tried a few ways but nothing worked.
Please help me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Before I look deeper into your code: What I find a bit odd is this:

```
....
   {% for key,value in tables.items()  %}
   ....
      {% for key_page,value in value[0].items()  %}
      ....
```

You seem to use `value` as a loop variable in two loops. Using `value` the second time override the content of `value` of your first loop, this way modifying the content of `value`. Before I go into more detail please exclude that *this* is the cause of your error, as it likely might be.

Please rename the second `value` to something else - e.g. `value_page` - and then provide feedback. Thank you!

Comment: Okay. Please provide a working example with "fake"-data, so that we can look more closely into this problem.

Comment: here is the dictionary I am able to print it on my terminal..I want these records to be displayed on the graph. [2020-09-08 11:23:05,368] INFO in engine: tables - {'': '', 'B6BBB0CD00': 'B6BBB0CD00', '18060962': '18060962', '24047646': '24047646'}  [2020-09-08 11:31:12,448] INFO in engine: graph - {UUID('fda39ab8-de0e-11ea-8012-00e12901b102'): UUID('fda39ab8-de0e-11ea-8012-00e12901b102'), UUID('3a259e14-ece2-11ea-abcf-00e12901b102'): UUID('3a259e14-ece2-11ea-abcf-00e12901b102')

Answer (score 0):

Your function
def stats()
....
return ...

Doesn't have a `return`statement

Take into account that there are two parts:

- Back-end (python)
- Front-end (html and/or javascript)

With this in mind you need to pass info from one to another.

#### From Back-end to Front-end via return

For example:

```py
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello world'
```

or

```py
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', variable1 = 'animal')
```

or

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', variable2= {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2')
```

Then you can read the values of variables like this on `index.html`

```html
<!doctype html>
<title>Hello from Flask</title>
{% if variable2 %}
  <h1>Value of first element in dict {{ variable2['key1'] }}!</h1>
{% else %}
  <h1>Variable2 is not defined </h1>
{% endif %}
```

#### From Front-end to Back-end:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('blueprint_name.') }}" method="POST">
        <button name="filename" type="submit" value="">Generar plantilla</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: I've tried those things before none of it actually works and all it gives is a jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: str object has no element 0

Comment: the message is indicating you that you are attemping to do [0] when you have to do ['key']. The [0] works for lists type objects.

Comment: ive tried that as well and it gives jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute ''

Comment: @thegreat_one could you update your code with the return statement and the route using?